# Possibility to report/flag/downvote a whole user (instead of an answer)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, post-ban, users

Sometimes I feel there's a need for downvoting a whole **user** (not a specific answer).  I'll illustrate with an example. Take a look at [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3564350/sibi-a) and, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243089/how-can-a-buyer-without-being-redirected-to-paypal-complete-the-transaction):

- You can see his questions tend to be broad/unspecific/vague (look other questions in his profile)
- He is even begging in the comments for someone to vote!
- In all his questions he's always asking for help "asap" (like his question is more important than other's?). Specially annoying after you see his profile and find out he doesn't seem to be doing any research at all before posting the question (sometimes, it looks like not even common sense is being used by him to solve the issue).
- If he hasn't got an answer, he's frequently commenting in his own questions begging (again) for help.
- It looks like the kind of user who thinks it's easier to spend 2 minutes posting a question than 5 minutes searching the Internet.

What do you think of users like this?  Should we be able to downvote a whole user for posting such poor quality questions so frequently?

Comment: The existing moderation tools work fine for situations like this. People can change; it would be better to encourage that user to learn how to use the site through moderation than to just completely shut them down.

Comment: Focusing on the *user* instead of the *content* is a slippery slope. There are indeed problematic users around, but we should only judge their posts. If they ask too many bad questions, they will be throttled then banned, so the problem will go away on its own.

Comment: What would flagging or downvoting the whole user do?  What does this accomplish?

Comment: @bluefeet for example, requesting more reputation before letting him post again, in an effort to make him note the problem he is causing. As Fish Below the Ice mentions in his answer, if there are actually mechanisms to prevent the user (based on throttling), that would do  (Y)

Comment: @maganap There are already things in place to block users posting bad content.  But the key here is _content_ you are focusing on the user, not their posts.  If users post bad questions which are downvoted/closed, etc then they are likely to hit a question ban.  Downvoting a user doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Judge the content, not the person.

Downvote poor content. There are mechanisms in place that will throttle (and, in some cases, prevent questions from) persistent askers of poor questions.

Comment: Nice to know. I thought downvoting the content would only affect the content itself but not the user, and that those kind of users could go on forever... If that mechanism actually exists, great then (Y) Thanks!

Comment: @maganap: See: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/3524344)