# Flag/Report certain accounts?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, users

Can there be a feature, so that if there is an account which is constantly spamming or something like that, if you have enough reputation, vote to shut down the account, or if you have even more reputation, maybe have the ability to flag the account and a moderator can immediately take a look at it. Also, there should be default report messages. These basically apply to the accounts and regular messages. What it does is when you are too lazy to write a reason to report, you can select a pre-written report that fits the scenario. The pre-written report feature may not be abused though, and should have some penalty if that happens. The pre-written reports should be reports that could fit many common scenarios for example: Advertising, Spam etc.

Comment: Flag the *actions*, not the *users*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possibility to report/flag/downvote a whole user (instead of an answer)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280411/possibility-to-report-flag-downvote-a-whole-user-instead-of-an-answer), [Can we flag a specific user?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285159/can-we-flag-a-specific-user)

Answer (score 3):

You could raise a custom flag on one of their posts detailing the issues which will be seen by a moderator who will investigate and take the appropriate course of action.

Comment: I guess that would work, but I'm suggesting a feature in which you could flag the account instead of the question, and possibly (worst case scenario) ban the account instead of the question.

Comment: If they are spamming enough, it will get noticed pretty quickly and their whole account will probably get banned.

Comment: You have a good point there. :)

Comment: @IMMLGPRO1337420 It doesn't really matter where the button is. The moderator is presented with the text you wrote, and he or she will look at it and take the appropriate action, which may range from "do nothing" to "delete a question" to "nuke the account across the entire SE network". Whether that's a flag for just one question or "an account" is really not that important and merely a user-interface issue. What matters is the text you write to the moderator explaining the issue.